# Pyspark parse highly nested json (Prometheus)

Tags: python, json, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would really love some help with parsing nested JSON data using PySpark-SQL because I'm new to PySpark. The data has the following schema:

**Schema**

```
root

|-- data: struct (nullable = true)

|    |-- result: array (nullable = true)

|    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)

|    |    |    |-- metric: struct (nullable = true)

|    |    |    |    |-- data0: string (nullable = true)

|    |    |    |    |-- data1: string (nullable = true)

|    |    |    |    |-- data2: string (nullable = true)

|    |    |    |    |-- data3: string (nullable = true)

|    |    |    |-- values: array (nullable = true)

|    |    |    |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)

|    |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)

|    |-- resultType: string (nullable = true)

|-- status: string (nullable = true)
```

This is an example of the JSON file (input):

{"status":"success",

"data":{"resultType":"matrix","result":

[{"metric":{"data0":"T" ,"data1":"O"},"values":[[90,"0"],[80, "0"]]},

{"metric":{"data0":"K" ,"data1":"S"},"values":[[70,"0"],[60, "0"]]},

{"metric":{"data2":"J" ,"data3":"O"},"values":[[50,"0"],[40, "0"]]}]}}

**My Goals** I would essentially want to get the data into the following data frames:

1-

```
data0 | data1 | data2 | data3 |values
```

example output dataframe:

```
data0  | data1 | data2  | data3 | values
"T"    |   "O" |    nan |    nan|   [90,"0"],[80, "0"]
"K"    |   "S" |    nan |    nan|   [70,"0"],[60, "0"]
nan    |   nan |    "J" |    "O"|   [50,"0"],[40, "0"]
```

2-

```
time | value | data0 | data1 | data2 | data3
```

example output dataframe

```
time | value |data0 | data1 | data2  | data3 
90   |   "0" |   "T"|    "O"|   nan  | nan
80   |   "0" |   "T"|    "O"|   nan  | nan
70   |   "0" |   "K"|    "S"|   nan  | nan
60   |   "0" |   "K"|    "S"|   nan  | nan
50   |   "0" |   nan|    nan|   "J"  | "O"
40   |   "0" |   nan|    nan|   "J"  | "O"
```

Also , if there are any ways to speed up this process using spark's parallelism capabilities , that would be great because the parsed json files are in gigabytes.

Comment: Please provide example of input and output data.

Comment: Please check the question again , I made an update. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the first dataframe, you could use:

```py
df = (
    df.withColumn("data0", F.expr("transform(data.result, x -> x.metric.data0)"))
    .withColumn("data1", F.expr("transform(data.result, x -> x.metric.data1)"))
    .withColumn("data2", F.expr("transform(data.result, x -> x.metric.data2)"))
    .withColumn("data3", F.expr("transform(data.result, x -> x.metric.data3)"))
    .withColumn("values", F.expr("transform(data.result, x -> x.values)"))
    .withColumn("items", F.array(F.lit(0), F.lit(1), F.lit(2)))
    .withColumn("items", F.explode(F.col("items")))
    .withColumn("data0", F.col("data0").getItem(F.col("items")))
    .withColumn("data1", F.col("data1").getItem(F.col("items")))
    .withColumn("data2", F.col("data2").getItem(F.col("items")))
    .withColumn("data3", F.col("data3").getItem(F.col("items")))
    .withColumn("values", F.col("values").getItem(F.col("items")))
    .drop("data", "status", "items")
)
```

Result:

```
root
 |-- data0: string (nullable = true)
 |-- data1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- data2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- data3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- values: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)

+-----+-----+-----+-----+------------------+
|data0|data1|data2|data3|values            |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+------------------+
|T    |O    |null |null |[[90, 0], [80, 0]]|
|K    |S    |null |null |[[70, 0], [60, 0]]|
|null |null |J    |O    |[[50, 0], [40, 0]]|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+------------------+
```

To get the second, it's the same but with additional `explode` for values:

```py
df = (
    df.withColumn("data0", F.expr("transform(data.result, x -> x.metric.data0)"))
    .withColumn("data1", F.expr("transform(data.result, x -> x.metric.data1)"))
    .withColumn("data2", F.expr("transform(data.result, x -> x.metric.data2)"))
    .withColumn("data3", F.expr("transform(data.result, x -> x.metric.data3)"))
    .withColumn("values", F.expr("transform(data.result, x -> x.values)"))
    .withColumn("items", F.array(F.lit(0), F.lit(1), F.lit(2)))
    .withColumn("items", F.explode(F.col("items")))
    .withColumn("data0", F.col("data0").getItem(F.col("items")))
    .withColumn("data1", F.col("data1").getItem(F.col("items")))
    .withColumn("data2", F.col("data2").getItem(F.col("items")))
    .withColumn("data3", F.col("data3").getItem(F.col("items")))
    .withColumn("values", F.col("values").getItem(F.col("items")))
    .withColumn("values", F.explode("values"))
    .withColumn("time", F.col("values").getItem(0))
    .withColumn("value", F.col("values").getItem(1))
    .drop("data", "status", "items", "values")
)
```

Result:

```
root
 |-- data0: string (nullable = true)
 |-- data1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- data2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- data3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- time: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)

+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+
|data0|data1|data2|data3|time|value|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+
|T    |O    |null |null |90  |0    |
|T    |O    |null |null |80  |0    |
|K    |S    |null |null |70  |0    |
|K    |S    |null |null |60  |0    |
|null |null |J    |O    |50  |0    |
|null |null |J    |O    |40  |0    |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+
```

---

- Update:

Example of automating `data` names and number of results:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
import json

data_names = []
number_of_results = 0
with open("test.json", "r") as f_in:
    raw_data = json.load(f_in)
    for item in raw_data["data"]["result"]:
        number_of_results += 1
        for key in item["metric"].keys():
            if key not in data_names:
                data_names.append(key)

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.option("multiline", True).json("test.json")

for data_name in data_names:
    df = df.withColumn(
        data_name, F.expr(f"transform(data.result, x -> x.metric.{data_name})")
    )

df = (
    df.withColumn("values", F.expr("transform(data.result, x -> x.values)"))
    .withColumn("items", F.array(*[F.lit(x) for x in range(0, number_of_results)]))
    .withColumn("items", F.explode(F.col("items")))
)

for data_name in data_names:
    df = df.withColumn(data_name, F.col(data_name).getItem(F.col("items")))

df = df.withColumn("values", F.col("values").getItem(F.col("items"))).drop(
    "data", "status", "items"
)
```

The result is the first dataframe (same as above)

Comment: Thanks for the answer . What if I don't know the keys of the metric dictionary ? for example , it might be (data4 , data6 , etc) is there any workaround for this problem?

Comment: @Samo You're welcome. Do you have access to parse the JSON before loading it as a dataframe?

Comment: Yes , I have an access.

Comment: @Samo Updated to give example of automating data names, but it really depends on your dataset. Sometimes it's not possible to automate without exploring the input dataset.

Comment: Thank u very much for the update . Do u have any recommendations to speed up the process of loading the json file to a spark dataframe, cuz it takes a lot of time to parse large files?

Comment: @Samo You're welcome. I'd have to think about that. Try posting a new question for that issue to get more information and opinions.

Comment: Hello again , I just discovered one thing about ur solution ; The output dataframe just have only 3 rows , but it should have as many rows as the number of elements in the result array in the schema. Can u update the answer accordingly?

Comment: @Samo You could count the number of elements in the array before loading it to the dataframe and update the part `withColumn("items", F.array(F.lit(0), F.lit(1), F.lit(2)))` to set as many rows as you want. Let me know if you get stuck.

Comment: Thanks for ur comment. so may u write the update ? if for example the number of elements is stored in count **variable**.  because I'm new to pyspark.

Comment: @Samo Updated. Try that. Also, this is a bit out of scope of the question. Be sure to include all needed requirements in your future questions so we don't go back and forth.

Comment: Thank u and sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: @Samo You're welcome. I hope I helped you resolve the issue.